# Where do i find the ValueType constructor in .net source code?

Tags: c#, .net

May seem uninteresting, but I'm learing C# and was looking at the ValueType class. It says here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx that the syntax for the constructor is 'protected ValueType()'.

My question is where can i actually see this constructor in the source code? I looked around and can't find it. Closest thing i found was in 'Type Class', but then I can't identify the connection between class ValueType and class Type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find it anywhere. The only place you *might* have found it is in the .NET Framework Reference Source for the [`ValueType` class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs), but it does not contain any constructor, it merely defines `ValueType` as an `abstract class`, with an implicit compiler-generated constructor. Because the class is `abstract`, the implicit constructor is `protected`.

You can see this with your own types too:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
abstract class C { }
static class Program {
  static void Main() {
    // prints nothing: C has no public constructor
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(C).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null));

    // does print: C does have a non-public constructor
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(C).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't find it in the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs).  Which is normal, a class doesn't have to explicitly declare a constructor.  If not provided, the C# compiler auto-generates one.  Required to call the base constructor, System.Object's in this case.

It is *protected* because the ValueType class is abstract.

Answer (score 1):

There is no constructor defined in the [source code of that type](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs).

MSDN says the constructor is `protected`, but this is a consequence of the class being `abstract`. This is implicit.

`ValueType` is a class used only for boxing purposes (just like `Enum` is used for enum boxing). It provides different default implementations for `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and that's about it. These methods are virtual, and inserting `ValueType` in the class hierarchy for boxed value types will let the CLR resolve the calls of these methods to the more suitable implementations, because **two identical boxed values should be considered equal**, unlike two identical class instances, which by default will use reference equality.

I don't think you should need to worry about it, as it is more of an implementation detail than anything else.

On the other hand, the `Type` class is used for reflection purposes. It represents a type in the type system (like a class/struct/interface). `typeof(SomeType)` will return a `Type` instance, and so will `someInstance.GetType()`.

Some test cases:

```
object boxed = 42;
Console.WriteLine(boxed.GetType().FullName);                            // System.Int32
Console.WriteLine(typeof(ValueType).IsAssignableFrom(boxed.GetType())); // True
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for the `ValueType` doesn't exist other than as a theory to make the class model in .NET complete.

The constructor for the `ValueType` class will never be called, because a value type will never be treated as a class. When you implement a value type you do that as a `struct`, and although it can have a constructor, that's different from a class constructor, and the `ValueType` constructor won't be called when you use a `struct` constructor.

The `ValueType` class serves as a container for methods that you can use on a `struct`, the compiler handles everything that makes a `struct` work as if it inherited from `ValueType`.